# Can't create new XHTML file in webapp directory with Netbeans / Gradle

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, gradle, netbeans-plugins

I recently moved to Gradle from Ant for my build system on a project with 20+ sub-projects. The move went perfectly after installing the **Gradle Support**  and **Gradle JavaEE SUpport** plug-ins. The project builds successfully and passes all test.

Now when I go to add a new .xhtml file to one of the web application, the *Location* field defaults to the Java source directory and I am not able to select any other location.

[Appearance of new XHTML dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu1or.png)

The same issue occurs if I attempt to create any file type normally targeted at the *webapp* folder. I can see the *webapp* folder in the Projects UI listing and can edit existing files without any problems.

1. Is this a known issue?
2. Is there any way to add the webapp folder to the *Location* dropdown?

I don't want to have to move back to Ant as it's just too complicated for nested builds. I could try Maven but I like simple hierarchical nature of Gradle.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Netbeans 8.0, Gradle Support 1.3.1,  Gradle JavaEE Support 1.0
Gradle 2.0
Java JDK 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a missing feature. Better to raise the question to module author attention. The project is hosted on GitHub - https://github.com/hildo/netbeans-gradle-javaee-project As you will see it is a spare time project so it is unlikely if it gets fixed.

I think that technically Gradle JavaEE Support needs to define a `SourceGroup` for webapp resources and then 'new from template' wizard will offer it.

Comment: Sounds right. I've cloned the gradle-javaee project and have been searching for a solution for a while. I've tried adding the path to the `getJavaSources` method but that's been deprecated and isn't being called. It's not clear from the Netbeans documentation where this should be added. If you have any guidance or hints as to where the `SourceGroup` needs to be added it would be helpful.

Comment: Best forum to ask is 
dev@platform.netbeans.org or possibly nbdev@netbeans.org (https://netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html#technologies). At least some NetBeans developers are tracking those.